Will Kubernetes scale to maxReplicaCount directly based on threshold in ScaledObject?
The metric server has a simple REST API endpoint that returns count in the response body.
In my scaled object yaml, say I have given below:
minReplicaCount: 1
maxReplicaCount: 10
pollingInterval: 90
cooldownPeriod: 120
triggers:
  - type: http
  metadata:
    valuePath: $.count
    threshold: 1000

Will KEDA scale directly to 10 replicas if count threshold is met? I am worried KEDA directly scaling between 1 and 10 and 1 and 10 everytime the trigger returns count>=1000. I rather wanted replica count to be in multiples of 1000 till max 10.

Generally KEDA will use the HPA to scale the resources. So the HPA will gradually scale up and scale down based on the metrics provided rather than scaling directly to the desired count.
To answer your question KEDA will gradually scale up the resources rather than directly scaling all at once and there is no direct way to make the scaler to scale the count based on the multiples of 1000 as you mentioned. But you can customize your metric to return the value in the multiples of 1000.
You can refer to this Auto Scaling Microservices with Kubernetes Event-Driven Autoscaler (KEDA) blog written by Suman Das to know the working nature of KEDA.
Refer to this github issue on cooldown period to know how the KEDA and HPA handle the cooldown period.
Refer to this KEDA scaling document to know more about how the KEDA scaling will work and check this KEDA FAQs to get more information.
